# Simpler way to overload a method for a variable with multiple types?

Tags: c#

I couldn't find the answer from searching, but maybe I'm not asking it the right way. I have a program with lots of matrix-type functions that take in 3D matrices (in the form of 1D-2D jagged arrays) and performs functions on elements. However I often need to use the same function but with differently typed arguments: int[][,] and float[][,] and double[][,].

So far I've just been rewriting the same method but changing the type, but I have tons of these things and it's a real pain to keep rewriting "re-typed" methods.

```
private float SomeFunctionA(float[][,] d)
{
    float sum = 0; 
    for (int k = 0; k < d.GetLength(0); k++)
        for (int j = 0; j < d[0].GetLength(1); j++)
            for (int i = 0; i < d[0].GetLength(0); i++)
                 sum += d[k][i,j];
    return SomeFunctionB(sum);
}

private float SomeFunctionA(double[][,] d)
{
    double sum = 0; 
    for (int k = 0; k < d.GetLength(0); k++)
        for (int j = 0; j < d[0].GetLength(1); j++)
            for (int i = 0; i < d[0].GetLength(0); i++)
                 sum += d[k][i,j];
    return SomeFunctionB(sum);
}
```

Is there an easier way to allow different types? It would be great if there was a way to have a generic main method with the functionality (i.e. the 3 for loops and other body code), and then helper methods which take a different type and call the generic method for each case.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no operator constraints in C# generics so I woul use next:

```
    private interface ICalculator<T>
    {
        T Add(T x, T y);
        // you may want to add more operations here
    }

    private class Int32Calculator: ICalculator<int>
    {
        public int Add(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }
    }

    private int Int32SomeFunction(int [][,] d)
    {
        return SomeFunction<int>(d, new Int32Calculator());
    }

    private T SomeFunction<T>(T[][,] d, ICalculator<T> calculator)
        where T : struct 
    {
        T sum = default(T);
        for (int k = 0; k < d.GetLength(0); k++)
            for (int j = 0; j < d[0].GetLength(1); j++)
                for (int i = 0; i < d[0].GetLength(0); i++)
                    sum = calculator.Add(sum, d[k][i, j]);
        return sum;
    }
```

For this solution you may create few more classes but you may support any operator (not only +) in this case.

Comment: See the other solution by Alexei that uses delegates to do this same thing in quite a bit less code.  Also note that, as I say in my answer, both solutions add a fairly noticeable performance cost which can be prohibitive for these low level mathematical operations.

Comment: @Servy Yes I agree but as I have mentioned 'For this solution you may create few more classes but you may support any operator (not only +) in this case'. If you have to use -,/,* operators ot Math.Abs function you will have to pass a lot of aggregators.

Comment: @Serve Also good point about function calls. I agree it may hurt performance but it depence on count of dementios used.

Comment: It seems you don't understand that solution.  Utilizing a delegate approach you can utilize any function, as well as using any type.  The end result will be almost identical to what's here, it will just take a lot less code to do it, and it will also semantically represent what's going on better (i.e. you name the function in the interface `Add` even though you may not be adding the items).

Comment: Thanks for the example of how to do this; this makes sense to me now.

Comment: @Serve i undestand the solution. I agree that in your scenario there will be less code. But for example what if you have to use +, - and * operators in one function (e.g matrix multiplication). In my case you will have to add Multiplay method to ICalculator interface and use it in calculation. What will you do with lambdas in your case? you will have to pass two functions one for * and one for +. In this case my solution is more general. Probably for this concrete solution you approach is more elegant. That is my point.

Comment: @petro.sidlovskyy And what is preventing you from passing an additional delegate if that's what's needed?  Keep in mind that using delegates results in code that's virtually identical to the code you have here, it just uses less code to do it.  It lets the compiler do much of the work for you.

Comment: @Serve >>>And what is preventing you from passing an additional delegate if that's what's needed? Answer: The number of delegates to pass. It may be more than one or two or five. Depend on the method logic. Plus it's harder to reuse them. Anyway I don't say you solution is bad. Both are simmilar and it depends on situation which is better.

Comment: @petro.sidlovskyy It's not my solution, it's another users.  My answer says that while it's possible to do it, you should just do what he's been doing because it is generally not feasible.  Next, when using @ replies it's rather important to spell the name properly for notifications to be sent; just use auto-complete if typing "Servy" is too hard for you.  Yes, if you got to the point where you needed 5 functions it may make sense to have an interface.  This isn't such a case, this case only has a single function, and a delegate is essentially a one-function interface with easier syntax.

Comment: @Servy oh sorry for misspelling. Yes I agree with your last comment. And I have agreed that solution you are talking about is more elegant for this particular case. I have just proposed more general idea. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, for these fundamental numeric types, not really.  There's no interface they implement that defines the `+` operator.  Anything that you try to do using reflection, dynamic, passing in a summation/aggregate function, etc. will result in a pretty significant performance cost.  Since matrix operations such as this are so frequently done in very performance intensive environments the reduction in code is rarely worth the cost of generalizing the methods.

Comment: Ah I see. Well the methods I put here are just simplified examples. In reality many of the functions are full of various conditionals and calls to other functions. But I will check the performance; re-writing them might be worth the performance benefit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use generic function and pass delegates to aggregate and handle result. As Servy mentioned the cost of delegates may be significant. You need to measure and see if basic approach like below would work for you. If performance of these operations is important keeping separate versions is fine approach. You can also check if using Jon Skeet's MiscUtil support for [Generic operators](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html) will make give acceptable performance.

```
private T SomeFunctionA<T>(T[][,] d, Func<T, T, T> aggregate, Func<T,T> postProcess)
{
    T sum = default(T); 
    for (int k = 0; k < d.GetLength(0); k++)
        for (int j = 0; j < d[0].GetLength(1); j++)
            for (int i = 0; i < d[0].GetLength(0); i++)
                 sum = aggreagate(sum, d[k][i,j]);
    return postProcess(sum);
}
```

`aggregate` (in LINQ terms, other common name "reduce") is to perform original "sum" similar to [Enumerable.Aggreagate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218.aspx) more generic version with signature `Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate>`. `postProcess` just abstracts handling result and code can be rewritten by calling generic version of `SomeFunctionB` if one exists. For original code usage would be:

```
 SomeFunctionA<float>((sum, current) => sum + current, SomeFunctionB);
```

Comment: What about `SomeFunction<string>()`?

Comment: @des This method would work with any type you'd ever need, so long as you can come up with an aggregate function you found meaningful.  It's basically just the LINQ `Aggregate` but for a 3D instead of 1D data structure and without all of the extra overload types.

Comment: ah yeah, now I get the `Func<T, T, T> aggregate`.

Comment: @Servy, thanks, should be better now :). Fixed types and added link to inspiration `Aggregate` function.

Comment: You should probably take some inspiration from `Aggregate` as to the function arguments.  In particular I'm thinking of a seed.  (It can be optional if you prefer.)  Addition is fine starting with 0, but if you want a multiplicative aggregate then you'll want to seed the aggregate with 1, as an example.  Complex times, i.e. data structures being aggregated would also need an empty value, rather than `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use text templating?

Create a new file called 'Overloads.tt':

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
using System;

namespace MyNamespace 
{
  public partial class Generated 
  {
  <# 
    var desiredTypes = new[] { "int", "float", "double" };
    foreach(var type in desiredTypes) {
  #>
  private <#=type#> SomeFunctionA(<#=type#>[][,] d)
  {
      <#=type#> sum = 0; 
      for (int k = 0; k < d.GetLength(0); k++)
          for (int j = 0; j < d[0].GetLength(1); j++)
              for (int i = 0; i < d[0].GetLength(0); i++)
                    sum += d[k][i,j];
      return SomeFunctionB(sum);
  }

  private <#=type#> SomeFunctionB(<#=type#> input)
  {
    return default(<#=type#>);
  }

  <# } #>
  }
}
```

When you save it, out pops `Overloads.cs` - with all your methods.

This is similar to how C++ templates work too.

A couple of notes:

The line `var desiredTypes = new[] ....` creates an array of strings which is then used to drive the loop inside which your overloaded methods are generated.

It makes sense to generate the class as `partial` so you can mix-in the more traditional code.

Comment: whoa! I had no idea you could do this. Definitely saving this one. thanks